# Would completeness of topologically equivalent metrics imply equivalence?

Tags: real-analysis

Opoitsev states in  'A Converse to the Principle of contracting Maps', 1976:

*Equivalent metrics are also topologically equivalent. The converse is false, but the following easily checked statement is true: If two metrics d1 and d2 are topologically equivalent and the spaces (X, d1) and (X, d2) are both complete, then d1 and d2 are equivalent.*

He says it is easy to check, but I am not sure. Is that statement true and if so, how can it be proved? Or are there other necessary conditions for topological equivalence to imply equivalence?

Comment: Here's a possible hint (I'm still thinking about this myself). Metric equivalence requires that we can write $ad_1 \leq d_2 \leq bd_2$ for constants $a,b$ that work everywhere, whereas topological equivalence lets the constants change point from to point. Perhaps try taking a Cauchy sequence of points for which the constants get bigger and bigger (if this can be done), and then looking at what happens at the limit point.

Comment: Thank you for your hint. Do the constants in topological equivalence depend on one of the points, or both, such as a=a(x), b=b(x) or a=a(x,y), b=b(x,y)?

Comment: It should only depend on one of the points, I think. At each $x \in X$, you can nest a small ball in $d_1$ with balls from $d_2$, but the ratio of the the $d_1$ ball's radius, and the radii of the $d_2$ balls might change.

Comment: Can you give the definitions of "equivalent" and "topologically equivalent" that you are using?

Answer (score 2):

If "equivalent" means $ad_1\leq d_2\leq bd_1$, this is wrong.

Take $X=\mathbb N$, with $d_1(u,v)=\vert u-v\vert$ and $d_2(u,v)=1$ if $u\neq v$. 
Then both metrics induce the discrete topology and $\mathbb N$ is complete with respect to both. But certainly you cannot find a constant $a>0$ such that $d_2\geq a d_1$ since $d_1(0,n)=1$ for all $n\geq 1$ and $d_2(0,n)=n$.

If "equivalent" means "uniformly equivalent", as suggested by Daniel, this is wrong as well.

Take $X=\mathbb N\cup\{ n+3^{-n};\; n\geq 1\}$, with the same distances as above. Then $d_1$ and $d_2$ again induce the discrete topology on $X$, and $X$ is of course complete wrt $d_2$. Moreover, $X$ is also complete wrt to $d_1$ since it is closed in $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R$ is complete wrt $d_1$. Finally, $d_1(n, n+3^{-n})\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ but $d_2(n,n+3^{-n})=1$ for all $n\geq 1$; so $d_1$ and $d_2$ are not uniformly equivalent.

Comment: I'm pretty sure "equivalent" means uniformly equivalent, and not Lipschitz-equivalent here. So $\bigl(\forall \varepsilon > 0\bigr)\bigl(\exists \delta > 0\bigr)\bigl(d_1(x,y) < \delta \Rightarrow d_2(x,y) < \varepsilon\bigr)$, and of course with the roles of $d_1, d_2$ interchanged.

Comment: I think you're right...

Comment: My example was going to be $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ with $d_2(x,y) = \delta_{xy}$, and $d_1((k,\ell),(m,n)) = \frac1k$ if $k=m$ but $\ell \neq n$, $1$ if $k\neq m$, and of course $0$ if $(k,\ell) = (m,n)$.

Comment: It works fine as well; in fact it is the same.

Comment: Equivalence of metrics means that both spaces have the same Cauchy sequences.

Comment: Not quite the _same_, but close enough, the same principle. Seems to be the natural idea when looking for a counterexample here. You may consider replacing "seems to be wrong" with "is wrong", with "seems" it sort of looks you were rather unsure of it.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Aha, that's the first time I meet that definition. Up to now, I've only seen topological, uniform and Lipschitz-equivalence.

Comment: Yes, it would be nice to have a different name to avoid confusion with the topological version. A place where you encounter this definition is on Koblitz's **$p$-adic analysis** book, for example.

Comment: I never met this definition either. Anyway, with it the statement is trivial...